# How to print a single cell in a csv file using bash script or awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

I'm having problems printing just one cell from a .csv file. I was only able to print a single column, but not a single cell.

Here's the command I use to print a column:

`BEGIN {FS = ","}
{print $1,$3}`

And I execute it using:

`cat test.csv | awk -f test.awk`

[My .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKBEW.png)

I want to manipulate the .csv file by each cell using bash or awk.

Thank you!

Comment: Your command applies for all lines. If you want to print just the first cell of the first line you have to write NR==1{print $1}

Comment: 1) don't attach screenshot, paste some example **TEXT** from your input file(csv) 2) show the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here some simple script. it will out B3 CELL. you can increase head parameter for get cellid.

```
cat file| awk -v FS=',' '{print $2}'| head -3 | tail -n 1
```

or

```
## C2 CELL
cat file| awk -v FS=',' '{print $3}'| head -2 | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me, but the `'{print $3}'` part of the line can I substitute a variable in place of the $n? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. Did not get your point. Can you please explain some example ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 cat a.csv|column -s, -t| cut -d' ' -f<col>|sed '<row>!d'
```